# What is the correct idiom to say that "I read" many papers "without considering the details"?

Tags: idioms

What is the correct idiom to say that "I read" many papers "without considering the details" only to get the necessary pieces of information I needed and in a very fast way. Is there one? Is it a formal idiom?

Comment: None are "idioms" but there are several verbs in common use: *I **scan** the newspapers every morning.* /*I **look through** the newspapers every morning.* *I **glance at/through** the newspapers every morning.* and also the delexical form *I **have a glance at** the newspapers every morning.* / *I **take a look through** the newspapers every morning.*

Comment: @Greybeard 'Flick through' can also be used as in "He flicked through the newspaper looking for any salacious items"

Comment: If tempted by *peruse,* resist; usage in that sense seems to be increasing, but the older established meaning is quite the opposite, and readers would be left to determine which sense applies. *American Heritage* has a usage note on it [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/peruse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Skimming**, **scanning**, or **skim reading** are all terms for this sort of thing. All would be acceptable in formal writing, although a single word isn't an idiom. They have slightly different meanings, however.

[This page](https://www.bbc.co.uk/teach/skillswise/skimming-and-scanning/zd39f4j) from the BBC's studying skills website differentiates the two, referring to skimming as when you "look through a text quickly to get the gist (the general idea)", while scanning refers to looking through a text for a particular piece of information (e.g. if you look through a document to see if it mentions something or includes a formula or address you want).

Answer (score 1):

**leaf through something**

> to quickly turn the pages of a book or a magazine, reading only a little of it:

*The waiting room was full of people leafing through magazines*.

[Cambridge Dictionary]